# How to restrict selection of options in md-multiple-select?

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material, multi-select

I need to restrict the user to select only 2 options from the multi-select options.....i checked with multiple-limit like `multiple-limit="value here"`...
Here is the[Codepen](https://codepen.io/DeekshaM/pen/pwrgVo)....

Comment: As far as I see the google and documentation there is no explicit solution. I would write my own md-select-max-selection directive and handle this scenario there.

Comment: @Ursache....so there is now way to achieve this from material side??

Comment: I cant find any. Lets see other suggestions :)

Comment: if u can....please help me by provide that directive you mentioned in the first comment...

Comment: I will during the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I read in the question comments, limiting selections is not (yet) supported out-of-the-box from the directive. But, we can have following workaround to get something like that achieved:

We would add a `ng-change` which listens to the directive's `ng-model` and gives us latest value. We then decide whether the latest value has exceeded the limit of selections, if so, we assign the model a previously saved copy with maximum selections.

Assuming the limit is 2 in the example below:

```
$scope.changed = function(val) {
  if(val && val.length > 2) {
    $scope.myModel = $scope.prevModel;
  } else {
    $scope.prevModel = val;
  }
}
```

[**Working codepen**](https://codepen.io/tanmayrajani/pen/EXvKKb)

Comment: interesting....but just open the console,put the val in console.log in change function and check the first,second and third boxes....your val contains 3rd checked value which means the the ng-model holding.....which is not the required value

Comment: @SaEChowdary it will be overwritten below.. where are you console logging it? can you fork the codepen and share here?

Comment: my bad mate....i didn't check the view part....this is fine and will get back to you if i got any queries

Comment: @SaEChowdary meanwhile you can upvote the answer if it helps :) sure get back to me if queries

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer, here is my custom directive:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRoNWx

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      scope.$watch(function () {
              return ngModel.$modelValue;
           }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
               if (newValue && newValue.length > attrs.mdSelectMaxSelection) {
                 ngModel.$setViewValue(oldValue);
                 ngModel.$render();
               }
           });
    }
```

Also you can use validators for the model, and notify the user why he cannot select more elements. Furthermore you can directly use the validator names in your template.

More info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController